# How to program UItoolbar buttons to load a new website in UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiwebview, uitoolbar, uitoolbaritem

I am working on an IPhone app and i have a UIWebview that by default loads a url.

I need to create a UIToolbar with three buttons under UIWebview which will allow users to hit the buttons and load a new url in UIWebview?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? How far have you got?

Comment: I have created the UIWebView and also the toolbar. i just need to program the buttons on the toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add three buttons to your toolbar( This can be easily done by using the Interface builder(IB) and connect them to there respective IBAction in the IB.

now when tap on a a button you can do like this.

you have a UIWebView say myWebView //declared in .h file and properly linked with the your View using IB.

when you are done with the basic initialization

for button1 press

```
   -(IBAction)button1:(id)sender
    {
          NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
          NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
          [myWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
    }
```

so by clicking on the button1 google webpage is loaded in your webView.

do the same for other button also.
:)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. but i need to know how i can do it with the UIToolbar buttons. thanks

Comment: UIToolbar button are same as a normal button, the only difference is that you have to add UIBarButton instead of UIButton. If any problem persist then ask me.

Answer (score 0):

These methods and properties of `UIWebview` maybe help:

```
- (void)reload;
- (void)stopLoading;

- (void)goBack;
- (void)goForward;

@property(nonatomic,readonly,getter=canGoBack) BOOL canGoBack;
@property(nonatomic,readonly,getter=canGoForward) BOOL canGoForward;
@property(nonatomic,readonly,getter=isLoading) BOOL loading;
```